# How to access the muliple database in a same time with JDBC not in JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, mysql-workbench, spring-jdbc, mysql-connector

I just created a sample project in Spring Boot using CRUD operation & JDBC. Now, I want to get the data from two different databases at the same time

I need to get two table values for the use of the conditional statement. but there is one problem two tables are in two different databases in MySQL. How do I access the different databases and use them in the same API call?

Comment: By "in the same API call", do you mean in a single SQL query, like a join? You can't do that.

Comment: Not like that in joins, we can access two tables with the same filed names.
here two tables have names & fields but different databases like local-DB and Main-DB in MySQL  can we access two DB in a single API call ?

Comment: You mean REST API call? You can do whatever you want in a REST API service.

Comment: Yes in REST API service do u have any idea or references for that